# Diferenças entre formas de referenciar um namespace

Tags: php, namespace

Eu gostaria de entender porque em alguns exemplos de códigos, as pessoas importam as classes da seguinte forma:

```
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
```

e não apenas:

```
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
```

Existe alguma diferença em iniciar com uma **"\"**?

Nos meus testes para as minhas classes o resultado foi exatamente o mesmo para as duas formas de uso. Por isso, gostaria de saber se existe de fato uma diferença ou é apenas opcional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesse caso não existe nenhuma diferença.

Porém imagine o seguinte cenário:

Você tem a classe `App\User` e a classe `Services\User`.

```
namespace App\User;

public function teste() {
   $services = new Services\User;
}
```

Esse exemplo provocaria um erro visto que ele iria procurar em `App\User\Services\User`

Já se a barra fosse colocada antes a classe seria encontrada, pois ele iria usar `\Services` como a raiz.

Quando usamos o `use` ele desconsidera o `namespace` atual, não sendo necessário utilizar a `\`.

Comment: Sim isso eu entendo. O problema é que costumo ver essa contra "\" no inicio do próprio "use". Isso que não faz muito sentido para mim.